# Are promise handlers (.then/.catch/.finally) always asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

Check this: https://javascript.info/microtask-queue The very first line says

> promise handlers .then/.catch/.finally are always asynchronous

But they always execute in sequential order. Only when it fails in the middle It jumps to catch. Then how come it is asynchronous?

Comment: They are not always. `let x = 1; new Promise(r => r(x)).then(console.log); x = 2;`  prints `1` but would have printed `2` if it was always asynchronous.

Comment: @Reactgular So you mean to say it was a mistake by them ?

Comment: Short answer; no, not always. Long Answer: It can't be guaranteed due to the nature of the event loop. You can read up more on it in [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/sync-async/ch1.md) - scroll to the event loop section.

Comment: @Reactgular Wait. Why do you compare the handler's code with code below the promise? Even in the article, they have given an example of something similar. But the statement seems to do nothing with code outside the handlers

Comment: running `let x = 1; new Promise(r => r(x)).then(console.log); x = 2;` is misleading.  You are just proving that the code inside the promise factory method runs synchronously.  But the question is about when the _then_ continuation callback runs.  Run `x = 4; new Promise(r => r(x)).then(() => console.log(x)); x = 5;` and you will see that it prints 5, showing that the continuation callback is asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the *design* of a promise that requires their usage to be either synchronous or asynchronous. The intention is that the programmer is free from worrying about the code being either, and should therefore *assume* an asynchronous side effect will always take place.

One of the most popular (yet irritating) questions on stack-overflow is the following:

```js
function fooBar(promise) {
   let y;
   promise.then(value => y = value);
   return y;
}
```

> Why does `fooBar()` always return `undefined`?

If *everyone* who uses a promise makes the assumption that they are all *asynchronous* there would be fewer bugs as a result, and improved clarification of how to use them.

Asynchronous means that the handler will not execute during the same JavaScript stack (event queue) and therefore the above should always yield `undefined`.

When a *synchronous* promise is used the above *actually* works. Which can be confusing to some developers who don't understand the difference between the two. It also means the result of the function is *unexpected* since the *internal* nature of the promise can not be determined to be either *synchronous* or *asynchronous* from the outside.

Comment: Thanks. I read something like this. Correct me if I am wrong. To tackle asynchronous execution we can use callbacks. But callbacks have some drawbacks as it may lead to callback hell or ununderstandable code. So, the promise is an alternative of callbacks which saves us from these drawbacks. This was my understanding as of now. But all of sudden we suddenly say it is asynchronous. I understand it works in a asynchronous way. I thought it is a replacement of callbacks.

Comment: @logidelic Yes. I am new to frontend

Comment: @AjithKumar we have a wide range of options to handle async problems in JS. They include callbacks, promises, async/await and observables (also known as reactive programming). Learning about these is a journey where you should really master callbacks first, then promises and then async/await and finally rxjs. Not understanding clearly how promises work makes for poor use of async/await. So keep reading and experiment to see what happens.

Comment: @Reactgular Okay. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: There's nothing in the _design_ but the Promises/A+ spec indeed _requires_ that promise callbacks occur asychronously -- never synchronous.  This makes things simpler for developers who then never have to worry about whether a promise is "sync" or "async" and how your example code would play out -- it will always play out the same when using compliant implementations.  See rule 2.2.4 https://promisesaplus.com/